# C# Google Sheets API - Protecting a range

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to protect a range in a google sheet using the sheets API (v4) in a .NET project.
I've been able to create a sheet and move it to the desired folder using the Drive API, but now I need to protect a certain range. I'm unsure how to form the request. I'm thinking I may need to use the batchUpdateRequest - but not entirely sure.
I have this so far:

```
            var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(PathToServiceAccountKeyFile).CreateScoped(Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.SheetsService.ScopeConstants.Spreadsheets);

            var service = new Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential
            });

            var body = new Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data.Request();
            body.AddProtectedRange.ProtectedRange.ProtectedRangeId(){

            };

            var request = service.Spreadsheets.BatchUpdate(body, fileId);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to protect a range:

```
        var spreadsheetId = "spreadsheet id"; //can get from sheet url
        var sheetId = "sheet id";
        var range = "A1:B10";

        var request = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest()
        {
            Requests = new List<Request>
            {
                new()
                {
                    AddProtectedRange = new AddProtectedRangeRequest
                    {
                        ProtectedRange = new ProtectedRange
                        {
                            Range = new GridRange
                            {
                                SheetId = sheetId,
                                StartRowIndex = 0,
                                EndRowIndex = 9,
                                StartColumnIndex = 0,
                                EndColumnIndex = 1
                            },
                            Description = "Protected Range",
                            WarningOnly = false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        service.Spreadsheets.BatchUpdate(request, spreadsheetId).Execute();
```

[AddProtectedRangeRequest docs](https://www.any-api.com/googleapis_com/sheets/docs/Definitions/AddProtectedRangeRequest)

Comment: Thanks! This seems like it will do the trick - just struggling to get the sheetID. I always want to apply this to the first sheet, so I assumed the ID would be 0. Doesn't seem to be the case though, so I guess I can retrieve that using the sheets API too? I'll have a play!